# Toggle container open when click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to create a website to navigates trough links. So when a click on a highlighted text it sends me to a different part on the website. 
But a part of the text is inside a toggle container that only opens when clicked. 
I'm using the following code, but it is not working.

```
<div class="toggle-wrap">        
    <span id="eindhoven" class="toggle-title">Eindhoven</span>            
    <div class="toggle_container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat 
    </div>
</div>


<script> 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        if (window.location.hash.indexOf('eindhoven')==1) { 

            $('toggle_container').show();
        }

   });

</script>
```

Comment: toggle_container is missing a `.` or `#`. If its a class use `.toggle_container` if its an id use `#toggle_container`

Comment: Do you want to open the div when <span id="eindhoven"> is clicked, or when the location hash contains eindhoven?

Comment: when the location hash contains eindhoven

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the solution, but you're not specifying what kind of selector you want to show:

```
$('.toggle_container').show();
```

You need the "." to specify it's a class you're looking for.

Comment: this only works when i refresh the page. When i click on the link it doesn't open the toggle container. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because the the evaluation of window.location.hash is only done at loading time. So, I would also add a click event listener as well. Otherwise, I'd try and think of another approach. Or, possibly look at some kind of JS router library that could help with this sort of thing, and watches the location all the time.